# Backbone model validate not triggering

Tags: backbone.js

I have overridden the Backbone.Model and extended my own Model with a validate method but it doesn't seem to trigger when updating my model with a set including the validate: true flag.

```
    Mod.Field.Model = App.Base.Objects.BaseModel.extend({
        url: "../WebServices/Myclass.asmx/GetData",
        defaults: {
            DisplayName: ""
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (attrs.DisplayName == "") {
                return "DisplayName cannot be an empty string.";
            }
        }
    });
```

In my CollectionView:

```
item_view.model.set({ "DisplayName": event.target.value }, { silent: false, validate: true });
```

Nothing seems to trigger the validate method on the model when calling the set.  I have tried called this as well:

```
item_view.model.isValid();
```

But that doesn't trigger it either.

Using Backbone version 1.1

Comment: Have you override the model.set method ?

Comment: The only method i have overridden is sync.

Comment: If you test `item_view.model.get("DisplayName")` do you get the value you have set ?

Comment: I get back the same value using that get on DisplayName that I just set on that model.  Very odd.  It seems like the overridden Backbone.Model I created is causing issues some how.

Comment: Something with the model override is causing issues.  In this simple test the validate was called right when set was fired with no issue.

Comment: Also, the validate get's fired when calling save on the model.  Just not sure why setting the "validate: true" on the set doesn't have it fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being my Collection that I had overridden that was setting the default model to one that I was not actually using.

This fixed the issue:

```
this.collection = new App.Base.BaseCollection(this.model.get("mydata"), { model: Mod.Field.Model });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below works....but still the question is why the code above will not work with the overridden model?

```
Mod.Test = {};

    Mod.Test.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "",
        defaults: {
            DisplayName: ""
        },

        validate: function (attr) {
            if (attrs.DisplayName == "") {
                return "DisplayName cannot be an empty string.";
            }
        }
    });

    Mod.Test.ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "div"

    });

    var newView = new Mod.Test.ItemView({
        model: new Mod.Test.Model()
    });

    newView.model.set({ "DisplayName": 123 }, { validate: true });
    newView.model.get("DisplayName");
```

Just tested another scenario.  I replaced the Mod.Test.Model with my overridden one with the sample code and it works.  The culprit seems to be the way I was getting the view back from the CompositeView for the model.

```
updateItem: function (event) {
var event_target = $(event.target);
var zero_length = event.target.value.length == 0 ? true : false;
var item_view = this.children.findByCid(event_target.attr("data-viewcid"));
```

Comment: See above, the issue seems to be how I was getting the model from the CompositeView to update the model.  What is wrong with findByCid